# Save HTML from one page to another page onclick

Tags: php, jquery

I know I could use a php include to read the html from a file on the server but how do I write a file to the server once the user clicks to navigate to the next page?

I have a div that is changed by jquery on the 1rst page. I want to read the changed div when the user clicks to go to the 2nd page and write the html from the 1rst page to the 2nd page.

Answer (score 5):

You can use combination of javascript and php code.

**jquery**

get the value of changed div and place it into a hidden field, wrapped within a form tag and submit the form to the next page

**php**

and on next page, get your hidden field value from $_post array and display it.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a `div` that is changed via jQuery:

```
<div id="something">something here</div>
```

To access the HTML inside your div,

```
var myHTML = $('#something').html();
```

Then Use AJAX to send the value to the second page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'secondpage.php',
    data: {
        'key' : myHTML
    }
    type: 'post'
});
```

In secondpage.php, check for `$_POST['key']` as follows

```
if( isset($_POST['key']) ) {
  // myHTML was sent successfully
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a good idea to do this as users are clicking because it would take a while for the document to get updated, and what if multiple users were trying to access the same page? You can use something called a cronjob, which basically executes PHP from your site's server at a specified time interval. I did this to update my website with my Twitter feed every 10 minutes, but doing it on every click would be too slow. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. When the user clicks on "go to next page" link, send AJAX request to
   some PHP file.

   - The AJAX request should contain the div html (use
     jQuery: `$(this).html()`)
2. In the php file write the html, and return
       information to AJAX (true/false).
3. When AJAX success go to the next page.

Comment: The proposal of @RabNawaz more elegant than mine